# How can I get the last element using Xpath in Appium

Tags: java, android, xpath, automation, appium

For example, I have message elements in my Android app and all of them have a *resource-id* called *"message_view"*.
What I want is to get the last message with this resource-id using Xpath only. I have tried to use `[last()]`, but it does not work:

```
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("//*[contains(@resource-id,'message_view')][last()]"));
```

I know that I can use `findElements()`, and then `.get(list.size() - 1)`. But I want to understand how can I do this with Xpath only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xpaths, `[]` has a higher precedence over `//`, so in your given Xpath, the `last()` doesn't work because it's being executed first rather than last. Use a pair of parenthesis in order to force this to work as you expect:

```
(//*[contains(@resource-id,'message_view')])[last()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap locator with `()`, as it was mentioned in another answer.

I will explain difference between `//locator[last()]` and `(//locator)[last()]`

Let's imagine you have following DOM:

```
<div>
  <div>
   <p1></p1> // 1
   <p1></p1> // 2
  </div>
  <div>
   <p1></p1> // 3
   <p1></p1> // 4
  </div>
</div>
```

With `//p1[last()]` you'll find all p1 elements, that ARE last elements in their nodes (last of siblings), so it's 2nd and 4th p1 element.

By `(//locator)[last()]` locator, you'll find all p1 nodes, and pick the last one (which will be actually the last p1 node in DOM), so it's 4th p1 element.